# creating css tooltip formatting issue with underlines in a tag

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to created a pure css tooltip. I have the test code here: http://jsfiddle.net/RBdn4/

The only problem with this is that in Chrome, the text is underlining on the tooltip despite having the `text-decoration: none;` line in the css.

Any suggestions on how to get this to stop? The link should underline, but the `.tooltip` text should not.

Comment: +1 because it's a good question, and I can't see how to solve it.

Comment: @Spudley what, you can't see my answer? `;-)`

Comment: @Matt - heh. no, I hadn't refreshed the page! (and for some reason SO didn't pop up its notification)

Comment: Note that 'pure css' interactions aren't always accessible solutions. Sometimes it makes sense to use JavaScript for these things.

Comment: I would have thought JavaScript more of a potential barrier to accessibility as it can be switched off?

Comment: A true tooltip is a TITLE attribute, so is likely more supported by screen readers and such. Then via JS, you can take the attribute and style it as you see fit. In addition, you can start looking at using the newer ARIA standards (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) for accessible JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome applies the link's `text-decoration` to the `<div>` because it is a child of the `<a>`.

Add a wrapper element around the `<a>` and make the tooltip `<div>` a sibling instead of a child of the `<a>`. Show the tooltip when the wrapper is `:hover`ed.

Oh, and make that CSS make sense!

#### HTML

```
<span class="wrap">
    <a href="#">this is text</a>
    <div class="tooltip"> this is a tooltip</div>
</span>
```

#### CSS

```
.tooltip {
    color: #000000;
    display: none;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 250px;    
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

span.wrap:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/u66GT/

Comment: `<div>` is allowed inside `<a>` as of HTML5 (you just have to make sure that you don't have `display:block` elements inside `display:inline`, so as long as you chage the display property of the `<a>`, you can put `<div>`s inside it. It's just xhtml that's anal about that.

Comment: I haven't checked to see if the problem occurs in other browsers as well, but I'm really not surprised that Chrome behaves this way. Can't exactly put my finger on it, though.

Comment: According to the w3c's HTML5 validator you're right about `<a><div></div></a>` - it doesn't care about the `display` at all (which is not surprising, since HTML validity should be orthogonal to applied CSS).

Comment: You don't need the wrapper element; you can use the `+` selector.

Answer (score 0):

[Fix'd](http://jsfiddle.net/RBdn4/7/). You can't override `text-decoration` from the child. Also, don't put `<div>`s in `<a>`s, as **Matt Ball** points out.

Comment: **ahem** _"The link should underline, but the `.tooltip` text should not."_

Comment: Oh, wow, was that edited in or am I simply blind? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to prevent the underlining from happening in Chrome while the elements were nested, but I can solve the problem by making them siblings instead.

Simply remove the `<div>` from inside the `<a>` tag, and put it next to it instead, like so:

```
<a href="#">this is text</a>
<div class="tooltip"> this is a tooltip</div>
```

and use the CSS `+` selector (adjacent sibling) to select the hovered tooltip, rather than the child selector.

```
.tooltip{
    display: none;
}

a:hover+.tooltip{
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 250px;    
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

The only change to the CSS from your original is changing the space to a plus sign.

Note the `+` selector doesn't work in IE6. Hopefully you're not planning to support this crumbly old browser though, right?